# I want to change label side in top of my frame in pyhton tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-label

Here is my code to implement and change to label side in top of frame....

```py
def login():
    global login_screen
    login_screen = t.Toplevel(main_screen)
    login_screen.title("Login")
    login_screen.configure(background="lightpink2")
    login_screen.geometry("700x750+600+200")
    frame=t.Frame(login_screen,bg='pink',pady=150,padx=100)
    l=t.Label(frame, text="Please enter details below to login", bg="deeppink4", fg="white",width="50", height="2", font=("Calibri 16 bold", 13))
    l.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2,padx=5,pady=5,ipady=5)
    #t.Label(login_screen, text="").pack()

    global username_verify
    global password_verify
    global mobile_verify

    username_verify = t.StringVar()
    password_verify = t.StringVar()
    mobile_verify=t.StringVar()

    global username_login_entry
    global password_login_entry
    global mobile_login_entry
    
    t.Label(frame, text="Username * ").grid(row=1,column=0)
    username_login_entry = t.Entry(frame, textvariable=username_verify)
    username_login_entry.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=5)
    #t.Label(login_screen, text="")
    t.Label(frame, text="Password * ").grid(row=2,column=0)
    password_login_entry = t.Entry(frame, textvariable=password_verify, show= '*')
    password_login_entry.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=5)   
    #t.Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    
    t.Label(frame,text="Mobile number *").grid(row=3,column=0)
    mobile_login_entry=t.Entry(frame,textvariable=mobile_verify)
    mobile_login_entry.grid(row=3,column=1,pady=5)
    #t.Label(login_screen,text="").pack()
    
    t.Button(frame, text="Login", width=10, height=1, command = login_verify).grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=2,padx=10,pady=5)
    frame.pack(side="bottom",pady=200)
```

here is img its my current code and chage in top of side
[image]

Comment: We can help you if you explain more exactly what you want to do. Bring only the relevant code snippet, not all the code you wrote. And put all the code inside ```. You might also try some of your own solutions, maybe search the web about your problem or learn more about `tkinter` [Geometry Managers](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-grid/). successfully!

Comment: Play around on different values for those `pady` options.